# Insecure Direct Object References and Search Engines

Tags: security, reference, owasp

According to [OWASP Top 10 List](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4) one way to prevent insecure direct object references is to provide only indirect references. These are artificial references that are mapped to the direct (e.g. DB) references on the server. The mapping is stored in the session.

Unfortunately, this solution is not very search engine friendly. The links stored by the crawler would be invalid in another session.

Is there a way around this problem? Are there other solutions apart from mapping references or checking object access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a problem that doesn't exist :-)

Everything that a search engine must be able to crawl and see has to be public, because everything a search engine can see, can be seen by everybody. For data that is expected to be public -by definition- the object reference can never be insecure. Insecure means that it is supposed to be protected.

So if you are questioning this, take a step back and look closely at your data. If it must be crawlable, why are you trying to protect it? If it should be protected, why are you supplying it to search engines.

Comment: I'm not sure whether we understand the same by "insecure reference": An insecure reference is a public reference that can easily be altered, so that it points to an non-public object. E.g. there are two articles on a website: article A with id 12 is public, article B with id 43 is non-public. The public (and crawled) URL /article?id=12 uses a insecure reference, since it can easily be changed to show article 43, if no further precautions are made.

Comment: id=12 is not insecure, because it is public. id=43 however is insecure, because that document is not public. Start by splitting the page in a public page and a non-public page. You public objects should have their own id range (for instance, use a table with a primary key + the id of the document). For the private pages you can now use the techniques that are described in the Owasp document and you can have extra protections to prevent unauthorized users from accessing that page.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. But by splitting the id range, a kind of access control is introduced. So why would anyone want to use indirect references, if he has to implement some form of access control anyway? Is there an additional benefit?

Comment: OWASP doesn’t say that direct object references are always a bad thing, but they say that _insecure_ direct object references are. One of the solutions they offer is an indirect reference, the other solution is to have an access control mechanism (or both). The trick with security is to have multiple layers of defense.